# Bootsrap Buttons with dropdowns, convert to ng-bootstrap Buttons with dropdowns,

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular5

Im beginner to Angular,I want to know how to correctly  create this code for the **ng-bootsrap**  ,I can do it using bootstrap-4 but  I don't know Angular,
Im follow this [Ng-bootstrap drop down](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples) ,but not work
please help me ,
Thanks

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         Currency
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">USD</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AUS</a>
       
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ,Now its work for me , Recommend  for the  `ng-bootstrap` team

[GitHub](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2055)

[Live sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/mV6tridL2laHdY17Hp87?p=preview)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <div class="btn-group" ngbDropdown role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" ngbDropdownToggle>Action</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" ngbDropdownMenu>
        <button class="dropdown-item">One</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Two</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Four!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ng-bootstrap with Angular 5, you should install bootstrap via npm, like [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started). This is an [example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples)  about dropdown menu.
I'm using `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5` and I modified your code,  worked fine:

```
<div ngbDropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ngbDropdownToggle>
      Currency
    </button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">USD</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AUS</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Define a variable named items in your .ts file: `items = ['A','B','C']`, then replace your dropdown by:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</a>
```

Comment: Sir, Im all ready installed that,But I Cant do  set of the drop down , look at my snippet, im attach bootsrap-4 cdn, becuase I dont have Ng-bootstrap cdn

Comment: sir, you know how to bind  drop down?  i try t find some example but I dont see anything

Comment: look this one selected item not display http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: i mean like this http://plnkr.co/edit/MpzcXb?p=preview, but this one is  html code  include   for .ts file

Comment: You have to define your variable in .ts file. It's how Angular binding works.